# trying to create a new application but i receive error when verified using mobile code

Tags: facebook, mobile, verify

i'm trying to create a new application, so it's required to enter the Mobile number.
but when I submit the country code and my mobile number, I keep getting the same error

---

> "Sorry, we have already tried texting multiple codes and they all seem to have failed. Please click here to get help."

---

But the help page doesn't provide a solution for this error.

what can i do to solve this problem?